# Autohotkey shortcuts with AltGr lead to locked Ctrl key

Tags: autohotkey

I want to mimic some nice features of the NEO Keyboard layout without switching completely. Therefore I want to make some Hotkeys like this

```
<^>!m::Send, 1
return

<^>!,::Send, {Numpad2}
return
```

It does work, however when I use this to type 1 or 2, afterwards the ctrl key is locked, i.e. if I simply press 'a', then every text gets selected, etc. Pressing the actual Ctrl key reverts behaviour to normal. Exiting the script itself does not.
However the same files also contains

```
<^>!a::Left
return

<^>!s::Down
return

<^>!d::Right
return

<^>!w::Up
return
```

And here the problem does not appear.
I have tried versions with {Blind} and SendPlay but I cannot get it to work.
I also tried adding {Ctrl up} commands.

Comment: Have you tried `{LCtrl up}`?

Comment: I just tried
<^>!m:: 
    Send, {Numpad1}
    Send, {LCtrl up}
    return

and the error persists.

Comment: You need a newline after `::`.

Comment: I tried it with a newline after :: as well as after Send, {Numpad1}. The Error persists, and additionally if I keep AltGr pressed, I cannot enter multiple numbers, which is what I want to do.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Your code works fine for me.